# Filter the first n cases in SPSS based on condition

Tags: spss

I have a database in SPSS structured like the following table:

| ID | Gender | Age | Var1 | Var... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 7 | 3 | ... |
| 2 | 1 | 8 | 4 | ... |
| 3 | 1 | 9 | 5 | ... |
| 4 | 1 | 9 | 2 | ... |

I want to select only the first n (e.g.: 150) cases, where Gender = 1 and Age = 9, so in the table above the 3. and 4. case. How can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: Do you need the first 150 gender 1 and age 9, or do you need "from the first 150 records, select gender 1 and age 9" (which could be for example 40 records) ?

Comment: I want select the first 150 cases, where gender = 1 AND age = 9, beacuse there's more than 150 cases that meet those criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
compute filter_ = $sysmis.
compute counter_ = 0.

if $casenum=1 and (Gender = 1 and Age = 9) counter_ =1 .
do if $casenum <> 1.
    if ~(Gender = 1 and Age = 9) counter_ = lag(counter).
    if (Gender = 1 and Age = 9) counter_ = lag(counter) +1.
end if.
compute filter_ =  (Gender = 1 and Age = 9 and counter<= 150).
execute.
```

I am not sure if this is the most efficient way, but it gets the job done. We use the `counter_` variable to assign an order number for each record which satisfies the condition ("counting" records with meet the criteria, from the top of the file downwards). Then create a filter of the first 150 such records.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot! Unfortunately when I run this in the Snytax Editor (couldn't make it work in "Select Cases"), it deletes all the other records. I just want to set up a filter (variable), which marks these cases with a 1.

Comment: you did not mention this in your initial post; I have adjusted my answer to take this into account

Answer (score 1):

The below will select the first 150 cases where `gender=1 AND age=9` (assuming 150 cases meet that criteria).

```
N 150.
SELECT IF (Gender=1 AND Age=9).
EXE .
```

Flipping the order of `N` and `SELECT IF ()` would yield the same result.  You can read more about `N` in the [IBM documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/spss-statistics/28.0.0?topic=cases-overview-n-command#syn_n_of_cases_overview)

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I cannot make it work. I get the error code "incorrect variable name: either the name is more than 64 characters", and I couldn't find a solution anywhere. [This](https://www.ibm.com/mysupport/s/question/0D50z00006bk3ZOCAY/incorrect-variable-name-either-the-name-is-more-than-64-characters-or-it-is-not-defined-by-a-previous-command?language=en_US) didn't help, because all my variables are numeric type. What am I missing?